# Render MathJax in tag excerpts when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, bug, mathjax, tag-wiki-excerpt, tag-autocomplete

Tag wiki excerpts support MathJax, on sites where it's turned on. That is, except on an important place, when editing a question:

[image]

Both the tag popup and the [tag info page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/exponentiation/) do show rendered MathJax:

[image]

Comment: Might as well be a bug/overlook when they created the tags autocomplete.

Comment: [Related](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2750/510296) mod request, and [claim it is fixed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6576/510296) - must have become broken. Apparently, [sometimes it works and sometimes it's broken](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3269/510296).