# Why was the "×" removed from tag autocomplete/preview? Can it be brought back?

Tags: feature-request, bug, tag-autocomplete

Up until some days ago, when tagging a question, the popups would indicate that said tag had been used *x* times in the form of `[tag] × 2814`; see the following screenshot, courtesy of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341981/398063):

> [image: former preview when tagging]

The `×` symbol is gone now, and the numbers now look a bit confusing, to me at least. I also notice they're darker now (maybe part of [the ongoing CSS refactoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343758/398063) which has caused some UI regressions already).

> [image: current preview]

I feel like the `×` conveyed more information on the number next to it than no symbol at all. It's pretty common to have this letter/symbol denote a number of instances, and no symbol conflates a bit with the way tag scores are displayed, when it's not at all the same thing (this display kept the `×` though):

> [image: tag scores]

If this design change is intentional, what is the rationale behind it? If not, can it please be brought back?

Comment: I think my title is mildly unclear, if someone has a better inspiration, be my guest.

Comment: Title suggestion: "Why doesn't X mark the spot any more?"

Comment: The "x" was also removed from the main tag page. Screenshots [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8227560#8227560).